# Since moving HTTPS using cloudflare, the admin and login pages no longer work

Tags: 404-error, ssl, https

Recently routed our site through cloudflare as part of moving to HTTPS.

All the pages work apart from the administrative pages for which we get a 404 error. I don't really know what is causing the error.

Has anyone had this issue in the past?

Answer (score 0):

Several possibilities:

- Clear local and remote (cloud) cache.
- Try with a 'private' browser.
- Make sure that your wp-options table has the https: in both URL entries.
- Check your htaccess file for proper redirect.
- Look at the error logs.

Provide more info (edit your question) to help get answers.